# Nokogiri Ruby 'require' Issues

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm new to Ruby and I'm having a lot of trouble trying to use Nokogiri. I've been trying to find a resolution for hours now, so any help is appreciated. I tried searching for and using solutions from other related SO posts before caving and posting my own. When I run `ruby -v` I get: `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]`

(**Edit**: I have updated ruby with `updates-alternatives --config ruby` and selected `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1` but when I do `ruby -v` it is now showing version 1.9.3 WTF am I doing wrong here?)

I have a new project directory at `~/workspace/ruby/rubycrawler/` and I used Bundler to install nokogiri, which installed correctly:

```
Using mini_portile (0.5.2)
Using nokogiri (1.6.1)
Using bundler (1.5.1)
Your bundle is complete!
```

Running `bundle show nokogiri` returns `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1`.

In the directory I'm running the script from I have a simple html file named "index.html". The script I'm trying to run is even simpler (or so I thought):

```
require 'nokogiri'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("index.html"))
puts page.class    # Nokogiri::HTML::Document
```

The error is `rubycrawler.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)`.

I also added `require 'rubygems'` even though I read it isn't needed for 1.9+ and still no luck.

A lot of searching shows *"Did you put this gem in your Gemfile?"*. So I generate a Gemfile and add `gem 'nokogiri'`. I try running the small script again and get the same error. I read *"Try deleting Gemfile.lock."* so I did but still couldn't get it to work. I then read to try testing it out in `irb` so I tested "open-uri" and "nokogiri" and here's what I got:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'open-uri'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> require 'nokogiri'
LoadError: no such file to load -- nokogiri
```

I'm really having a lot of trouble figuring this out, so really any help at all is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby tools like RVM, Bundler, etc., to the novice, appear to do a lot of magic, but really, there is no magic to them.  The key here lies in what Bundler actually does for you.  It manages a manifest of dependencies, BUT at runtime, those dependencies STILL have to get loaded somehow, and my gut feeling is that is what is not happening here.

Regardless of what version of Ruby you are using, if you are using Bundler, there's an easy way to do this.  Precede the command that starts your program with "bundle exec" and that will make Bundler edit Ruby's load path so that it includes all the things in the manifest (Gemfile.lock).

For example:

```
$ bundle exec ruby foo.rb
```

A additional note for anyone using RVM: RVM generally will modify the shebangs in the scripts that launch programs like "ruby" or "rake" so that they use the "ruby_no_exec" shell (or similar) instead of the plain old "ruby" shell.  That alternate shell is Bundler-aware and makes it generally unnecessary to type "bundle exec," but since the OP is using system Ruby, that's not applicable and commands should be manually prefixed with "bundle exec".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, but I'm confused by what you are getting at (sorry if I'm missing the point). when I do `bundle exec ruby crawler.rb` I still receive the same `require: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)`.

As for dependencies I had already installed the nokogiri dependencies using `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev.`

Comment: What happens if you `bundle console` in your app directory and then `require 'nokogiri'`?

Comment: @Eugene I receive the exact same error I'm being plagued with where it "cannot load such file".

Comment: @SMT, you mentioned you were new to Ruby and everything you explained looked like you're doing things the right way, except you made no mention do using "bundle exec".  Based on you not having mentioned that in your original post, I took a guess that that might be your problem, but it would appear I guessed incorrectly.  I agree with trying Eugene's suggestion as a method of troubleshooting this further.

Comment: @KentRancourt Sorry if I left out that piece of info, I've been trying so many things I let that one slip! I appreciate the help btw, setting up Nokogiri so far has been a huuuge pain and makes me wish for something like the BeautifulSoup module. At the end of the day when I finally get this working I hope it'll be a hardcore learning experience.

Comment: @SMT... you mentioned deleting your Gemfile.lock.  Do you still NOT have a Gemfile.lock?  If not, that could also be part of the problem.  You should re-run "bundle install" to re-generate Gemfile.lock and then try your program again with the advice from my original answer- using "bundle exec".

Comment: @KentRancourt I had redone all of that actually, once I found deleting Gemfile.lock didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @SMT, and yes... it's a valuable learning experience.  The learning curve on things like Bundler is a little sharp at first, but once you're over it, it's pretty smooth sailing and the knowledge you pick up along the way will server you well if you're going to continue using Ruby for any length of time.  Don't get discouraged.  :)

Comment: @KentRancourt Thanks! I'm new to Ruby but not programming in general and actually had a similar problem trying to install the Paramiko module for Python on a Windows machine which took a literal day to figure out. Onward I tread.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kent's answer, I would recommend switching to RVM instead of using the system installed ruby.  System rubies tend to be horribly out of date, especially when it comes to important things like features and security updates.  It might not help you in your current situation, but it would be well worth the time.  If you are unfamiliar: http://rvm.io

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll do that for sure, I've read about RVM on a lot of posts I was just hoping (or thinking) I could get something simple with Nokogiri up and running without it. I'm trying to keep my head up because this is making me miss how simple installations were with Python's `pip` haha.

Comment: For what it's worth, bundler isn't required.  It does help when dealing with Rails apps and the like, but if you want a global installation of a gem, you can definitely do that with `gem install <gemname>`